# Edit approved when I requested it not be

Tags: discussion, edits

I came across a post with an obvious formatting error, I hit edit and submitted my changes. Upon submitting my suggestion, I saw that someone else had beaten me to this and had made very similar changes to the edit I just submitted.

Upon seeing this, I tried (and failed) to find any way to retract my edit suggestion, so instead updated my edit with the comment:

> Please vote down - another user made the changes this edit intended to moments before I clicked the edit link.

However, my edit got approved any way (By what looks like 2 badge hunters). I don't want to hit that rollback button since neither version has any advantages over the other and it seems like it would be a pointless addition to the review queue.

Am I correct in my actions here?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19386260

Comment: Aren't you notified when someone edit while you're editing? Or just because I use "inline" version of edit (on PPCG)?

Comment: In this case I wasn't - possibly because I had used my browser back/forwards which seems to kill ajax on SE.

Comment: Maybe they didn't read your comment, only the edit suggestion itself. It's not a bad edit so without the comment i dont see any reason to reject it.

Comment: @AndréKool I don't think that the edit make the post better at all. Just some change in the spacing.

Comment: Changing the spacing can (greatly) improve the readability of a post. Don't underestimate how much impact spacing has on some persons reading the post.

Comment: @AndréKool How people format their code is very much a personal preference. Different people like different things.  Changing a post form the authors preferences to your own is not appropriate.  (In this case the meta OP didn't change the spacing at all, but someone else did in a conflicting edit, making it appear as if this user is rolling it back).

Comment: @AndréKool *"It's not a bad edit so without the comment"* - wut? Are we looking at the same edit? All it does is *unbalance* the spacing around `=` operators in SQL so that they've got a space before but none afterwards. I've never encountered any person or style guide that preferred unbalanced whitespace around any binary operator in any language, ever; one of the few universal style preferences that almost everyone instinctively has is that spaces around operators should be balanced. But even if some freak somewhere disagrees, it's *still* a pointless and arbitrary stylistic change.

Comment: @MarkAmery *"But even if some freak somewhere disagrees..."* —well, the question's first version has unbalanced whitespace around the operators :-) I am having difficulties interpreting the revision history, but to me it looks like Scoot's edit (rev. 3) was basically identical to McNet's (rev. 2) except that it left the unbalanced whitespace untouched, which makes it the better edit as it adheres to OP's formatting preferences. Given that, I am fine with the revision history and the final outcome.

Answer (score 6):

I'd approve your edit too.

> By what looks like 2 badge hunters

The reviewers simply compare "how it was" with  "how it become" and decide whenever or not to allow it. They don't have to read comment if edit is a clear improvement.

What happens is unusual. But don't worry, you cause no damage and to be honest, I "like your style" more, don't roll anything back.

Requesting "downvote" edit in comment is clearly not a way to fix "concurrency" issue like this. Posting on meta is.

Maybe

> I had used my browser back/forwards which seems to kill ajax on SE

can be fixed? Shall we add `[bug-report]`? But then you have to provide all details: which browser, how exactly it happens, so that the SO crew can reproduce it and fix.

Comment: I must say I'm glad the majority response I've had here has been positive - as far as browser details: Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10. I've noticed the ajax break before now but this is the first time it's caused issue for me. Navigate away from the question and hit back and any comments/answers/edits/deletes already applied by ajax get rolled back, and subsequent ones don't get applied until I hit refresh.

Answer (score -1):

I supposed it's also possible they read your edit summary and took pity on you since it was a mistake and a reject would count against you toward a ban.

> I don't want to hit that rollback button since neither version has any
>   advantages over the other and it seems like it would be a pointless
>   addition to the review queue.

I agree.

Much like your accidental edit is just a style change, rolling it back would be the same thing and you risk getting that rejected. If the edit caused actual harm it would be worth changing it but this you should just leave alone.